# Implement breadcrumbs with react, react-router and redux

Tags: redux, react-router, breadcrumbs

I had designed the action and reducer in below:

```
// Action Types
const PUSH_BREADCRUMB = 'PUSH_BREADCRUMB';
const POP_BREADCRUMB = 'POP_BREADCRUMB';

// ActionCreator
const pushBreadcrumb = (payload: { text, link }) => ({
  type: PUSH_BREADCRUMB,
  payload
});
const popBreadcrumb = () => ({ type: PUSH_BREADCRUMB });

// Reducer
const initState = [
  { text: 'Home', link: '/' }
];
const breadcumbsReducer = (state = initState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case PUSH_BREADCRUMB:
      return [...state, action.payload];
    case POP_BREADCRUMB:
      return state.slice(0, state.length - 1);
    default:
      return state
  };
};
```

Below is my component and router:
    //...import some components

```
// ...connect and map breadcrumbs
const Header = ({ breadcrumbs }) => {
  return (
    <ul>
      {breadcrumbs.map({ item, link } =>
        <li key={link}><Link to={link}>{text}</Link></li>
      )}
    </ul>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider>
    <Router>
      <AppContainer>
        <Header />
        <Route exact path='/orders' component={OrderListContainer} />
        <Route path='/orders/:id' component={OrderDetailContainer} />
      </AppContainer>
    </Router>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Then:

- Dispatch `pushBreadcrumb` in `OrderListContainer#componenetWillMount` and `OrderDetailContainer#componenetWillMount`
- Dispatch `popBreadcrumb` in `OrderListContainer#componentWillUnmount` and `OrderDetailContainer#componentWillUnmount`.

The excepted breadcrumbs is `Home > Orders > Detail`;

But when i stay in `/orders/:id` and refresh page, it will be `Home > Detail`.

Is there better way to implement breadcrumbs with redux?

Answer (score 0):

That happens because state is reset after you refresh. You can try to implement your solution with [persistent store](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-persist) - this will keep selected state keys to browser localStorage.